# LocationClient get location updates by distance

Tags: android

I am using a `LocationClient` for retrieving the current user location, and i'm trying to create a `LocationRequest` with a distance value as well as the update interval.

My code currently requests location updates by update interval:

```
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(updateInterval);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        if (mLocationClient.isConnected()) {
            mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);
        }
```

In the `LocationManager` there is a method to request location updates by distance

`public void requestLocationUpdates (String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [setSmallestDisplacement](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setSmallestDisplacement(float)) to set the smallest distance traveled between updates in meters. Just add this to your code.

> mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(SMALLEST_DISPLACEMENT);

Comment: ok thanks, i have missed that method.(will accept the answer in 10min)

Comment: glad to know it helped

Comment: @user1940676 Does it really work?? when i try to use it, the location updates happened before the smallest_displacement.

Comment: Do I need to remove setInterval() and setFastestInterval() methods if I add setSmallestDisplacement() Method?